# Invalid Argument in IE 11 in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm getting the error listed below in IE11. Code is working fine in Chrome, Mozilla and safari but creating issue in IE.

I have a garage in my project where user can add and remove the cars from garage. When i remove the car from garage it's showing error. "Invalid Argument"

**According to me the issue is with swiper slider when i removed the swiper from the section it works fine when i click on remove to garage http://prntscr.com/onfklt**

**Remove Function:**

```
remove(id) {

    let vm = this;
    vm.to = vm.to-1;
    vm.total = vm.total-1;
    var resultModel=vm.$global.inArrayModel(id,vm.carModel);
    vm.model.garageDataArray=vm.$global.remove_grage(id,vm.model.garageDataArray,this);
    vm.carModel.splice(resultModel,1);
},
```

**Remove garage function from global variable:**

```
inArrayModel(id, carModel) {
  var length = carModel.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (carModel[i].model_id == id)
      return i;
    }
    return false;
},


remove_grage(id, garageData, snotifyObj) {
    var result = this.inArray(id, garageData);
    if (result != 'false') {
      garageData.splice(result, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("garage", JSON.stringify(garageData));
      this.onerror(snotifyObj.$snotify, snotifyObj.$store, 'Removed from Garage');
    }
    return garageData;
},
```

Here is my code:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "Error: Invalid argument."
"Error: Invalid argument.
    at setTextContent (eval code:5718:3)
   at patchVnode (eval code:6317:7)
   at updateChildren (eval code:6178:9)
   at patchVnode (eval code:6304:29)
   at updateChildren (eval code:6178:9)
   at patchVnode (eval code:6304:29)
   at updateChildren (eval code:6178:9)
   at patchVnode (eval code:6304:29)
   at updateChildren (eval code:6178:9)
   at patchVnode (eval code:6304:29)"
```

Comment: @Andreas I have updated the questions. Please check now.

Comment: In DevTools, click on the line with "setTextContent" - you will see where the error occurs. Now put a breakpoint there and try to remove another car from the garage. You will see why the argument for "setTextContent" is invalid.

Comment: @IVOGELOV In IE 11, we cannot debug the code in detail. when i click on  "setTextContent" nothing happens because its not linked to that line

Comment: Perhaps you can share the code on CodeSandbox so we can troubleshoot it in action ? Otherwise your stacktrace is not very useful :(

Answer (score 0):

Think this link answers the problem:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/internet-explorer-garbage-collection-on-removed-nodes/17144

> "In case anyone finds this, the problem was that I was not clearing out the children of the other element before I replaced its innerHTML. Remove their children before overwriting, as Vue does not protect itself from IE11’s sloppy handling of data binding pointers. "

Answer (score 0):

So for me the issue was that the innerHtml of an element contained some text but was changed by none-vue code which caused the "Invalid argument." error in IE11. I recommend going around this problem by setting the innerHtml text using :text-content.prop="yourText" attribute or v-text="yourText" attribute on that element.

IE11 end of life: June 15, 2022... can't wait.